# velocity: how to find out if a field value contains a certain string

Tags: jira, velocity, jira-plugin

New to velocity and need some help. I'm getting a field value:

```
#set($value2 = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10010").getValue($issue))
```

But now want to check if `$value2` contains a certain string, for example `abc`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
#if($value2.contains("abc"))
    <p>display something, for example</p>
#end
```

just like you would do in java;

Regards

Comment: Thanks, that's actually how I figured it out myself. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `contains` to check value is in array as well

```
#if( $arrayName.contains($value) )
     <p>$value</p>
#end
```